# Ubuntu 14.0.4 - Mistake while installing

Tags: system-installation, kernel

This is the first time I install Ubuntu.

First I downloaded the universal usb drive, then I selected the location of Ubuntu, which was on my external hard drive, and I made a mistake by putting the destination to be the D drive, instead of the E drive.

I then went to my D drive, clicked on Ubuntu, I got prompted if I wanted to reboot now, I clicked yes. (I assumed I'd be able to go back to windows in case anything goes wrong.. Nope.. lol)

Now I'm getting the infamous [end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (2,0)]

All my data is backed up, so I don't have any important data on my HD.

I'm trying to hold shift while booting to get Grub, but that isn't working either. I'm pretty much stuck now. Any advice?

Comment: Reinstall maybe?

Comment: What do you want to do now?

Comment: I would like to get Ubuntu installed. I have the installation menu, but anything I pick leads to kernel panic error.

Comment: How can I reinstall? Is there a way I can boot back Windows?

Comment: Is there another computer you can use?

Comment: Yep! What should I do with it? @DavidBailey

Comment: Windows or Ubuntu?

Comment: Mac @DavidBailey

Comment: Posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your Mac computer, download the [image for Ubuntu 14.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso) to your hard drive. Once it's finished downloading, you can write it to a memory stick:

1. Open the terminal
2. Change directory to where you downloaded the file, e.g. `cd Downloads`.
3. Convert the ISO to an IMG by running:

   `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.img ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`
4. Run `diskutil list`.
5. Plug in your memory stick.
6. Run `diskutil list` to see which device was added (this is your memory stick).
7. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` replacing N with the number assigned to your disk.
8. Run `sudo dd if=ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=8m` to write the IMG to your memory stick, again, replacing N.
9. Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` to eject the disk, replacing N bla bla.

Now, you can plug the memory stick into your other computer and boot from it. It will work on a standard computer despite being written from a Mac.

From: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx